# How to run a packaged java file

Tags: java, cmd, package

Can anyone help me on how I have to run a java application which is in a package, from cmd?
Please give me the necessary line that I have to type.

**EDIT:** (Copied a clarifying comment from one of the answers below)

No I mean a normal Java aplication that belongs to a package, like:

```
package x; class SampleOnly{ }
```

How you compile (and run) that file.

Comment: Since nothing worked for you so far, I suggest you post the code so somebody can tell you exactly how to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **No i mean a normal java aplication that belongs 2 a package, like `package x; class sampleOnly{ }` hw u comple dat file**

This little "bash session" should explain it:

```
$ ls .                   # Current directory contains the "x" package
x

$ ls x                   # The "x" package contains a Sample.java file...
Sample.java

$ cat x/Sample.java      # ...which looks like this.
package x;
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from Sample class");
    }
}

$ javac x/Sample.java    # Use "/" as delimiter and
                         # include the ".java"-suffix when compiling.

$ java x.Sample          # Use "." as delimiter when running, and don't include
                         # the ".class" suffix.
Hello from Sample class

$
```

How to execute an arbitrary jar file, depends on how the jar file in question is pcakaged:

If it's packaged with a manifest containing a Main-class declaraton, you simply do

```
java -jar program.jar
```

If it's a regular jar-file you need to know the main class. Let's say it's `package.Main`:

```
java -cp program.jar package.Main
```

(I answered this (indirectly) here: [How to convert Java program into jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887473/how-to-convert-java-program-into-jar)) -->

Comment: What error message do you get? Could you paste your entire bash-session on pastebin.org?

Comment: package Sample;

class Test

{

 public static void main(String args[])

 {

  System.out.println("This class belongs to the package sample");

 }

}

That is the code which I want to run from cmd, please show me how it should be done

Comment: I thought that that was what I showed you :)  Have a look at this: http://aioobe.org/run_java.mpeg

Answer (score 2):

## A simple class is written as:

package **com.demo.pack**;

public class **Demo** {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Demo class from package : '"
            + Demo.class.getPackage().getName() + "'");

}
```

}

This  Demo class will be stored under these folders.. Folder sequence will be **com/demo/pack**.
Then the class will be found under pack folder.
Now open the command prompt..
I have stored that package in my 'D' drive. Type the following command.

**D:>javac com/demo/pack/Demo.java** -- press enter

**D:>java com.demo.pack.Demo**-- press enter..

Done!

Answer (score 1):

By package you mean a **.jar** file?

```
java [ options ] <class> [ arguments ... ]
java [ options ] -jar <file.jar> [ arguments ... ]
javaw [ options ] <class> [ arguments ... ]
javaw [ options ] -jar <file.jar> [ arguments ... ]
```

[Running Java applications](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rt.doc.20/user/java.html)

Comment: no i mean a normal java aplication dat belongs 2 a package, like
package x;
class sampleOnly{
}
hw u comple dat file

Answer (score 0):

If it is a jar that you are talking about then `java -jar filename.jar`

Comment: works only if the jar contains a manifest, and the manifest contains a Main-Class declaration.

Comment: Right. The answer depends very much on what the OP means by "Java Application in a package".

Answer (score 0):

And not to forget setting the main class and optional classpath in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: org.example.HelloWorld
Class-Path: greetings.jar
```

Have a look to the JAR specs at http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html

Comment: The OP does not seem to need help creating the jar, only running it.